# Improving execution time for multiprocessing

Tags: python, sage

I am trying to improve the performance of this code in terms of time without success for now. Even running in 32 processes takes like 5m. Maybe do you have any suggestions to improve the time of this code? Here `evaluated_f_bool_func_lst` is a list with `2**24` elements. The elements of this list are 1-length strings with values of '1' or '0' ("binary list").

```
from sage.all import *
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing


def create_ext_component_function_i(dim, chunk_i, chunk_size, evaluated_f_bool_func_lst):
    sum_y_str = []

    for y in range(chunk_i, chunk_i + chunk_size):
        prod = ""
        for i in range(dim):
            minus1 = ((-1)**(1&(y>>(i))))
            prod += f'(1-{str(minus1)}*x[{str(i)}])*'
        sum_y_str.append(f'{prod}{evaluated_f_bool_func_lst[y]}')
    return "+".join(sum_y_str)


def create_ext_component_function(dim, evaluated_f_bool_func_lst):
    sum_y = ""
    chunk_size = (2**dim)/32
    pool = Pool(32)
    results = []
    for i in range(0, 2**dim, chunk_size):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(create_ext_component_function_i, args=(dim, i, chunk_size, evaluated_f_bool_func_lst)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    join_results = [result.get() for result in results]
    print("+".join(join_results))
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    evaluated_f_bool_func_lst = load("evaluated_f_bool_func_lst.obj")
    dim = 24
    create_ext_component_function(dim, evaluated_f_bool_func_lst)
```

Comment: Even with the chunks the executing time of the function is very short and the overhead of feeding 2**19 tasks into the process pool takes its toll. Try to make the tasks larger!

Comment: Do you have over 16 cores in your cpu (i.e. to go with the 32 processes)?